# MASM doesn't recognize my TLS callback

Tags: assembly, callback, linker, masm, ida

I have produced an assembler listing of my `.C` source file. And in the C source i have implemented tls like this:

```
char *msg = "callback";
void NTAPI tls_callback(PVOID DllHandle, DWORD dwReason, PVOID lpVd)
{
    MessageBoxA(0,msg,msg,0);

}

#ifdef _WIN64
#pragma comment (linker, "/INCLUDE:_tls_used")
#pragma comment (linker, "/INCLUDE:tls_callback_func") 
#else
#pragma comment (linker, "/INCLUDE:__tls_used")
#pragma comment (linker, "/INCLUDE:_tls_callback_func")
#endif

#ifdef _WIN64
#pragma const_seg(".CRT$XLF")
EXTERN_C const
#else
#pragma data_seg(".CRT$XLF")
EXTERN_C
#endif
PIMAGE_TLS_CALLBACK tls_callback_func = tls_callback;
#ifdef _WIN64
#pragma const_seg()
#else
#pragma data_seg()
#endif

__declspec(thread) char *tlsData = "tls static data";
```

I have produced assembly listing of this C file, and tls now look like this:

```
PUBLIC  _tls_callback@12
PUBLIC  _tls_callback_func
PUBLIC  _tlsData

_TLS    SEGMENT
_tlsData 
    DB  00H
    DB  00H
    DB  00H
    DB  00H
    DB  00H
    DB  40H
    DB  30H
    DB  80H
_TLS    ENDS
CRT$XLF SEGMENT
_tls_callback_func DD FLAT:_tls_callback@12
CRT$XLF ENDS


_TEXT   SEGMENT
_DllHandle$ = 8                     ; size = 4
_dwReason$ = 12                     ; size = 4
_lpVd$ = 16                     ; size = 4
_tls_callback@12 PROC                   ; COMDAT

    push    ebp
    mov ebp, esp

    mov edx, DWORD PTR _msg

    push 0
    push edx
    push edx
    push 0
    call DWORD PTR __imp__MessageBoxA@16
; Line 34
    pop ebp
    ret 12                  ; 0000000cH
_tls_callback@12 ENDP
_TEXT   ENDS
```

I don't see that the tls pattern is produced however, i looked up in IDA PRO the pattern should be:

```
.rdata:004921A8 __tls_used      dd offset __tls_start  
.rdata:004921AC TlsEnd_ptr      dd offset __tls_end
.rdata:004921B0 TlsIndex_ptr    dd offset __tls_index
.rdata:004921B4 TlsCallbacks_ptr dd offset _tls_callback_func
.rdata:004921B8 TlsSizeOfZeroFill dd 0
.rdata:004921BC TlsCharacteristics dd 100000h
```

So do i need to define a new tls segment and place those patter in there? Or it should be in the data section?

I compile it like this:

`ml.exe listing.asm /coff`

I have looked up produced file inside ida pro, and i see that tls directory wasn't produced at all, how do i tell masm or its linker to make directory?

Comment: I'm unable to find any options for the linker or the assembler to generate the TLS directory. Probably the fastest workaround is to put the TLS structure in some segment (i.e. section), let the linker generate a symbol map and code a script that read the map file and patch the executable.

Comment: Never try to assemble and use the assembly output of the Microsoft C/C++ compiler. I don't know if it's the case here, but generally the assembly output generated by the Microsoft C/C++ compiler is incomplete and incorrect. Is your goal to have an assembly or C++ function called as a TLS callback?

Comment: @RossRidge to use tls from assembly using masm

Comment: @RossRidge i have found a solution, i will post an answer a bit later to this question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Microsoft linker uses the symbol `__tls_used` (on x86 systems) or `_tls_used` (on non-x86 systems) as the address of the TLS Directory. The TLS Directory contains a pointer to a zero terminated array of TLS callbacks. So by creating a suitable TLS Directory and giving it the name `__tls_used`/`_tls_used` you can have a TLS callback function in assembly code.

Here's an example program that demonstrates this:

```
    PUBLIC  __tls_used
    PUBLIC  start

    EXTERN  __imp__GetStdHandle@4:DWORD, __imp__WriteFile@20:DWORD, __imp__ExitProcess@4:DWORD

_BSS    SEGMENT PUBLIC DWORD FLAT 
tls_index DD    ?
_BSS    ENDS

_RDATA  SEGMENT PUBLIC PARA FLAT ALIAS('.rdata') READ

__tls_used:
    DD  OFFSET tls_start
    DD  OFFSET tls_end
    DD  OFFSET tls_index
    DD  OFFSET tls_callbacks
    DD  tls_bss_end - tls_end
    DD  0   ; chracterstics

tls_callbacks:
    DD  OFFSET tls_callback
    DD  0

main_msg:
    DB  "Main entry called.", 13, 10
main_msg_len = $ - main_msg

_RDATA  ENDS

_DATA   SEGMENT PUBLIC FLAT
tls_cb_msg:
    DB  "TLS callback called. Reason: 0", 13, 10
tls_cb_msg_len = $ - tls_cb_msg
_DATA   ENDS


_TLS    SEGMENT PUBLIC DWORD FLAT ALIAS('.tls')
tls_start:  
    ; put initialized TLS variable definitions here
tls_end:
    ; put uninitialized TLS variable definitions here
tls_bss_end:
_TLS    ENDS

_TEXT   SEGMENT PUBLIC PARA 'CODE' FLAT
    ASSUME  DS:FLAT

tls_callback:
    mov eax, [esp + 8]
    add BYTE PTR [tls_cb_msg + tls_cb_msg_len - 3], al

    push    -11 ; nStdHandle
    call    [__imp__GetStdHandle@4]

    push    0   ; lpOverlapped
    push    0   ; lpNumberOfBytesWritten
    pushd   tls_cb_msg_len ; nNumberOfBytesToWrite
    push    tls_cb_msg ; lpBuffer
    push    eax ; hFile
    call    [__imp__WriteFile@20]
    ret 12

start:
    push    -11 ; nStdHandle
    call    [__imp__GetStdHandle@4]

    push    0   ; lpOverlapped
    push    0   ; lpNumberOfBytesWritten
    pushd   main_msg_len ; nNumberOfBytesToWrite
    push    main_msg ; lpBuffer
    push    eax ; hFile
    call    [__imp__WriteFile@20]

    push    0   ; uExitCode
    call    [__imp__ExitProcess@4]
    int 3

_TEXT   ENDS

    END start
```

Note that above code isn't compatible with the Visual C++ runtime (CRT) implementation of TLS. If you're planing to work with C++ code then you'll want let the CRT provide the TLS Directory and other information. You can tell it to use one of your callbacks by putting a pointer to the function in the `.CRT$XL?` section where the question mark `?` is replaced by a letter from `B` to `Y`. Using the letter `B` will cause it to be called before the CRT TLS callback is called. Using a letter from `D` to `Y` will have it called after.  So the code you'd want would be something like:

```
_CRT SEGMENT PUBLIC DWORD ALIAS('.CRT$XLD')
     DD OFFSET my_tls_callback
_CRT ENDS
```